# 5 hour international layover in Tokyo Narita?

Tags: airports, layovers, tokyo, nrt

I have a 5 hour layover in Tokyo, between Hong Kong and Boston. Is that enough time to leave the airport and see the city? If not, is there anything I can do in the airport?

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7695/layover-at-tokyo-narita-airport-can-i-travel-outside-and-what-kind-of-visa-wou

Comment: Specifically, see http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/7696/1480 .

Comment: I'd take the time to get a nap if possible, or at least a decent meal, in between the flights...

Answer (score 1):

No, definitely not enough time to get to Tokyo and back comfortably, but you have enough time to visit Narita town (train works well), have a nice BBQ eel (unagi) lunch and do some shopping.

Comment: right totally impossible!  just enjoy the big airport.