# Transit in Japan

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit-visas

I m holing a passport of Indian. I m traveling  to Russia but my flight from Mumbai to Tokyo, Tokyo to Haneda, Haneda to Kansai. Kansai to Vladivostok. I have a airport change at Tokyo. Can I require a transit visa of Japan.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate because the flight from Haneda in this question is domestic, but the difference is immaterial: in both cases, passing through immigration at Narita is required.

Comment: Note also that the rule cited in an answer to [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7695/layover-at-tokyo-narita-airport-can-i-travel-outside-and-what-kind-of-visa-wou) does not apply here because NRT and KIX are in different areas for its purposes.