# Travelling with a non-revenue listing via Delta, I will fly from Manila-Narita-Seattle. Do I need a transit Visa?

Tags: visas, transit, japan

Travelling with a non-revenue listing via Delta, I will fly from Manila-Narita-Seattle. That said, I will be going from Narita to Seattle as a chance passenger. Do I still need to secure a Transit Visa, when I do not intend to go outside the airport? I am a Filipino citizen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Layover at Narita, Japan. Do I need a transit visa?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9027/layover-at-narita-japan-do-i-need-a-transit-visa) and [Layover at Tokyo Narita airport: can I travel outside, and what kind of visa would I need?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7695/layover-at-tokyo-narita-airport-can-i-travel-outside-and-what-kind-of-visa-wou)

Comment: As I understand it, it's sometimes not possible to remain airside if you're on standby for the next flight segment. I don't believe the suggested duplicate sufficiently covers standby/industry flights.